RStudio needs macOS Monterey but can't update, too little space
I am using RStudio for a coding class at university. I have macOS Catalina, and am using RStudio version 2024.04.2+764.
I need to update my Mac to macOS Monterey to be able to use the newest version of RStudio for some commands that aren't available in my current version.
The problem is I don't have the space on my Macbook Pro 2015 to update my Mac. I need to free up like 15gb of storage to update my Mac, not sure how to go about it. I've deleted plenty of old files etc. but still need more space. the "other" section in my storage is like 60gb but I don't know how to get rid of that.
Is there an online version of R studio that is compatible with Mac? Any other suggestions?

Here are the high level steps to freeing space. After each step, use Disk Utility to check how much free space is free.

Make sure you've emptied your trash and restarted your computer.
Check for Time Machine snapshots using Terminal: tmutil listlocalsnapshots /

If it returns any results, then you can delete them like so: sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots [snapshot_name]


Find large files. I recommend checking your Applications folder, since many apps are >1GB and that can be an easy way to clear space. Delete the app, then re-install it when you're done. Daisy Disk can help with this.
If you have iCloud Photos enabled, you could always turn on "Optimize Storage" instead of "Download Originals". The same applies to iCloud Drive.

note: these commands may be specific to Catalina, but the steps should be general.
